# How to keep page length where there is fewer results?

Tags: datatables

When searching through a table or navigating to the last page of the table there may be fewer results that the `pageLength` setting, so table shinks in height. I would like to prevent that by filling missing rows with empty rows. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you doing server side?

Comment: @TheGuest it does not metter really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `bScrollCollapse` property along with `sScrollY`.

As [documentation](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options) say:

> When vertical (y) scrolling is enabled, DataTables will force the
>   height of the table's viewport to the given height at all times
>   (useful for layout). However, this can look odd when filtering data
>   down to a small data set, and the footer is left "floating" further
>   down. This parameter (when enabled) will cause DataTables to collapse
>   the table's viewport down when the result set will fit within the
>   given Y height.

You can use it like this:

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable({
    "sScrollY": "400",
    "bScrollCollapse": false
});
```

An example of this is here http://live.datatables.net/ukiyek/115/edit#javascript,html

UPDATE:

You can also set the table height to 100% so that the whole area to be filled:

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable({
    "sScrollY": "400",
    "bScrollCollapse": false,
    "fnDrawCallback": function() {
       $(this).attr("height","100%");
    }
});
```

Example [here](http://live.datatables.net/ukiyek/118/edit)

UPDATE 2:

Found exactly what you are looking for in this thread http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/4112/possible-to-keep-datatable-height-static-even-when-filtering

Have a look at this [example](http://live.datatables.net/patejija/1/edit) which adds empty rows at the end.

Comment: Thank you, that is a half of the solution, the way I'd love it is to fill in the white space with empty rows. I guess that could be styled with css.

Comment: isnt this what you need?

Comment: Not quite. I wanted a spreadsheet-like experience, have a look: http://live.datatables.net/ruviwabu/1/edit (type `find me` in search bar) - when there's only 1 row with data, the rest 9 rows are *empty*

Comment: @Dziamid See my UPDATE 2 pls

Answer (score 2):

Adding rows seems like an easier and more generic solution than styling fixed scrolling area (as in MavRoSCy solution n.1).

So, here's what works for me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var table = $('#example').dataTable({});

  table.api().on('draw', function () {
        var info = table.api().page.info(),
          rowsOnPage = info.end - info.start,
          missingRowsOnPage = info.length - rowsOnPage;

        if (missingRowsOnPage > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < missingRowsOnPage; i++) {
             table.find('tbody').append(buildEmptyRow(6));
          }
        }

      });
});

function buildEmptyRow(columnsCount) {
    return '<tr class="empty">' + Array(columnsCount + 1).join('<td><div>&nbsp;</div></td>') + '</tr>';
}
```

Fiddle: http://live.datatables.net/ruviwabu/1/edit